# Cabal selects wrong linker

Tags: haskell, gcc, linker, cabal, ffi

I am working on a Haskell program which is linked to some old C++ code. I created a C interface and got it working with ghc only. Now I tried to convert the used Makefile into a Cabal project and now cabal on the last step selects the wrong linker.

Because of some dependencies I have to use a quite old ghc and gcc. So what I am doing is calling cabal (1.24.0.0.) like this:

```
cabal install --with-ghc=ghc-7.6.3 --with-gcc=/opt/gcc-3.3.6/bin/gcc  --with-ld=/opt/gcc-3.3.6/bin/gcc
```

For the compile- and intermediate configure linking all is ok, with `-v3` I get the following lines:

```
Using gcc version 3.3.6 given by user at: /opt/gcc-3.3.6/bin/gcc
Using ghc version 7.6.3 given by user at: /home/oswald/ghcs/bin/ghc-7.6.3
...
Using ld given by user at: /opt/gcc-3.3.6/bin/gcc
```

All works fine until the final linking step:

```
Linking dist/dist-sandbox-c45ed4c7/build/MISCconfig/MISCconfig ...
*** C Compiler:
'/opt/gcc-3.3.6/bin/gcc' '-c' '/tmp/ghc28340_0/ghc28340_0.c' '-o' ...               
*** C Compiler:
'/opt/gcc-3.3.6/bin/gcc' '-c' '/tmp/ghc28340_0/ghc28340_0.s' '-o' ...    
*** Linker:
'/usr/bin/gcc' '-fno-stack-protector' '-Wl,--hash-size=31' '-W
```

So the last line specifies `/usr/bin/gcc` as the linker, which is the system one and therefore I get link errors where it should be `/opt/gcc-3.3.6/bin/gcc` (have to use a pre-3.4.0 gcc because of link compatibility for one of the used C++ libraries and gcc 3.3.6 is the latest with the old ABI).

So what I am doing wrong? Cabal says it selects the linker from the old gcc but then actually uses the newer one from the system?

When I just use ghc with the `-pgmc /opt/gcc-3.3.6/bin/gcc` switch in a makefile all works but I would prefer to get a cabal sandbox working...

Comment: The `*** C Compiler:` and following output comes from ghc. How is cabal invoking ghc?

Comment: (If you just run `cabal build -v`, the last line will tell you.)

Comment: This is the output: [gist link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/41dd5f00401ce897e5cc7f190bc276ae)

Comment: There are a few things I don't understand in what you have presented, but I'm pretty sure that the `--with-gcc` flag is actually immaterial here. Do you have some secret `ghc-options` set perhaps?

Comment: At any rate, you need the flags `-pgml /opt/gcc-3.3.6/bin/gcc` to get ghc to use `/opt/gcc-3.3.6/bin/gcc` for the link step.

Comment: Ok, it cleared up a bit, I had the -pgmc in the ghc-options but not pgml. But now I get a message from ghc: could not execute /opt/gcc-3.3.6/bin/gcc (added full output to the gist above). That's really weird, because it executed it before.

Comment: A small add: I had to create a small wrapper script because cabal was sending illegal options to the old gcc, so the gcc binary itself is a wrapper script which just filters out the -fno-stack-protector switch and then calls the real gcc with the changed options. Still it works properly in all other situations I call it.

Comment: There is a telling comma at the very end of your gist.

Comment: You are right. That's it. Still getting link errors, but they are from a different reason. Thank you a lot! Could you convert your comment with the pgml to an answer so that I can flag it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This apparently had nothing to do with Cabal, which does not instruct GHC to use the C compiler specified by the Cabal option `--with-gcc`.

Use `-pgml` to select the linker as documented on the GHC man page.

(One point that may cause confusion for others and is worth mentioning. GHC always uses a **C compiler** to do the final link step. That means `-pgml` must refer to something like `gcc`, not something like `ld`. Consequently flags intended to be consumed by `ld` such as `-rpath` must be prefixed by `-Wl,` before being fed to `-optl`.)